# Debian image build from Ubuntu launchpad

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu

I downloaded the building scripts and some needed files to build debian cd image from the following link

[Debian_CD](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-cdimage/debian-cd/ubuntu)

In the README, it mentions I should edit the PATHs for the mirror at CONF.sh

```
# Paths to the mirrors
export MIRROR=${MIRROR:-$CDIMAGE_ROOT/ftp}

# Comment the following line if you don't have/want non-US
#export NONUS=/ftp/debian-non-US

# Path of the temporary directory
export TDIR=$CDIMAGE_ROOT/scratch/$PROJECT/$DIST/$IMAGE_TYPE/tmp
# Path where the images will be written
export OUT=$CDIMAGE_ROOT/scratch/$PROJECT/$DIST/$IMAGE_TYPE/debian-cd

# Where we keep the temporary apt stuff.
# This cannot reside on an NFS mount.
export APTTMP=$CDIMAGE_ROOT/scratch/$PROJECT/$DIST/$IMAGE_TYPE/apt

# Where extracted debootstrap scripts live
export DEBOOTSTRAP=$CDIMAGE_ROOT/scratch/$PROJECT/$DIST/$IMAGE_TYPE/debootstrap
```

# Where live filesystem images live
   export LIVEIMAGES=$CDIMAGE_ROOT/scratch/$PROJECT/$DIST/$IMAGE_TYPE/live

I am not really sure what does the "mirror" refer to and how to set the path correctly ?

Any advice will be appreciated.

=======================================================================
Post updated

Debian mirror site: [Link](http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/)

@cas Is this the one you refer to? However, how can I edit this CONF.sh by having this mirror site ? I don't find any clue yet.

Comment: MIRROR almost certainly refers to the ftp site that debian-cd will use to download the ,deb packages from.  Pick one close to you,